# How to calculate difference time value retrieved from phpMyadmin without using DATETIME?

Tags: php, time, hour, calc

I've done a bit of searching and there is a bunch of information on calculating the Time difference between two Times. But I'm not sure why my code isn't working.

This is Hotel Management system [input value interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSEoh.jpg).
This is the involved [database in phpMyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et5Yh.jpg).

If the customer is discharged after 12:00 at the noon, they will be fined $50.00 per hour in between 12:00 and time_out in [database in phpMyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et5Yh.jpg). And this is my code to calculate the total charge. I have no problem with calculating the duration of the date.

```
//discharge
$dateout = date_create($_POST['dateout']);
$timeout = $_POST['timeout'];

//book
$datein = date_create($_POST['datein']);
$timein = $_POST['timein'];

//calc duration
$duration = date_diff($datein,$dateout);
$days = $duration->format("%a");
```

But, I have a problem with Time calc.

```
if($timeout >= "12:00")
{
    $overtime = strtotime("12:00");
    $time = strtotime($timeout);
    
    $diff = $time - $overtime;
    $diffhour = $diff->format("%H");//in hour
                    
    $fine= 50;//$50.00
    $charge = $fine*$diffhour;
    
    if($row["bed_type"] == "3 person room")
    {
        $price = 175;
    }
    else if($row["bed_type"] == "1 person room")
    {
        $price = 280;
    }
}
else if($timeout < "12:00")
{
    $overtime = strtotime("12:00");
    $time = strtotime($timeout);
    
    $diff = $time - $overtime;
    $diffhour = $diff->format("%H");//in hour
    
    $fine= 0;//$0
    $charge = $fine*$diffhour;
    
    if($row["bed_type"] == "3 person room")
    {
        $price = 175;
    }
    else if($row["bed_type"] == "1 person room")
    {
        $price = 280;
    }
}
$totalprice = ($days*$price)+$charge;
echo $totalprice."<br>";
```

Most of the source on the internet is used DATETIME. But I believe there are other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Why would you not want to use the most common, tried and tested way of solving this problem using `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

Check-out delay hourly billing
The code below seems to suggest a more flexible method than yours.
Hope it helps.

```
$OverTimeStandardTime   =   strtotime( "12:00" );
$nowTime                =   time(); // unixtime

$OverTimeExist          =   $nowTime - $OverTimeStandardTime;
$addCharge              =   0;
if( $OverTimeExist > 0 )
{
    $addCharge  =   $addCharge + ( 50 * ceil( $OverTimeExist / ( 60 * 60 ) ) );
    //  1 hour is 3600 seconds per hour Additional charge processing
}

if($row["bed_type"] == "3 person room")
{
    $addCharge = $addCharge + 175;
}

if($row["bed_type"] == "1 person room")
{
    $addCharge = $addCharge + 280;
}

$totalprice = ($days*$price)+$addCharge;
echo $totalprice."<br>";
```

Comment: Please always endorse `elseif` as a single word in php.  Please see the addition-assignment operator `+=` for reduced syntax.